# Регулярное выражение с несколькими условиями для слова

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

```
preg_match('/^Привет\,? как\,? дела/i', $my)
```

Тут осуществляется поиск соответствия в тексте (`$my`).
Фразы

`Привет как дела
Привет, как, дела`

находит нормально.
А фразы:

`Привет. как, дела
Привет, как. дела`

или

`Привет 
как дела` (с переносом найти не может)

Не получается составить регулярное выражение с несколькими условиями для слова. У меня добавлены только запятые, а если ставлю точку, ничего не получается(
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: @Afimida, не забудьте принять ответ!

Comment: regex101.com - попробуйте чтобы не задавать таких вопросов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^Привет[,\.\s\r\n]*как[,\.\s\r\n]*дела/i', $my)
```

как то так

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь.!

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
'/^Привет\W? как\W? дела/i'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь.!

Answer (score 0):

почему бы в существующем авторском варианте паттерна к существующему флагу "/i" просто не добавить флаг "m" (multiline)?